# Controller arbitrary reject requests on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: python, google-kubernetes-engine

I've deployed few apps on Google Kubernetes Engine and exposed two controllers based on Flask Python, with Service which contains `type: LoadBalancer`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: controller
  namespace: ns-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: "5001"
    port: 5001
    targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

When I send Http Request via Python/Postman/Curl sometimes the Controller response with `200 ok`, But most of the time the request is being rejected immediately, without timeout or anything.

I had few speculation and thought that the load balancer reject the requests. Then I tried to use Ingress for expose the controller...
[using this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer)

The example in the tutorial works like charm, but forcing it on my app is not working. I'd change the service type to `NodePort`

ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: controller-ingress
  namespace: ns-app
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: controller
    servicePort: 5001
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: controller
  namespace: ns-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "5001"
    port: 5001
    targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

after waiting for ~15 minutes I entered to the Ingress external IP and I get `default backend - 404`.

Questions:
 1. How can I solve it?
 2. There is difference between `LoadBalancer` and `NodePort+Ingress`?

I need to expose my Flask Controller to have external IP in order to receive Http Requests.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a `rules` to the `spec`, i could overcome this issue.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: controller-ingress
  namespace: ns-app
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: controller
    servicePort: 5001
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: controller
          servicePort: 5001
```